# Get names of all the columns using API giving Error

Tags: api, dataextensions

I am trying to get all the columns names using API. below is the code I am trying ,i need to iterate through the API object to get the Name of columns.
But I am getting an error 
"ExactTarget.ExactTargetClient.APIObject object does not contain public definition of getenumerator" with this..

```
RetrieveRequest request = new RetrieveRequest();
            request.ObjectType = "DataExtensionField";
            request.Properties =
            new string[]
                {
                   "Name"
                };
            SimpleFilterPart sfp1 = new SimpleFilterPart();
            String[] sfp1Values = { Start.Text };
            sfp1.Property = "DataExtension.CustomerKey";
            sfp1.SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.equals ;
            sfp1.Value = sfp1Values;              
            request.Filter = sfp1;
            do
             {

            status = client.Retrieve(request, out requestID, out Results);                  
                 foreach (ExactTarget.ExactTargetClient.APIObject deo in Results)
                 { foreach (ExactTarget.ExactTargetClient.DataExtensionField prop in  deo)
                     { string name = prop.Name;                                                  

                    }

                 }
```

How should I solve this? Is there any other way to do it..
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use the describe object to get all of the fieldnames.

https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describesobject.htm

Comment: ..Thanks. DO I need to use any other "Reference" to access  DescribeSObject it give me error for the directive reference.